# Getting current day as number on masm?

Tags: datetime, time, masm, masm32

I want a program to do X task twice a month. So I though about getting the current day as number so I could do something like if day == 1 or 15 then do X

Does someone has a simple masm example to get the current day as a number?

I am looking for code simplicity so I can understand what it does, maybe there's some win api I could call.

Answer (score 2):

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
option casemap :none

include masm32.inc
include kernel32.inc
include macros.asm

GetLocalTime PROTO :DWORD
.data
LPSYSTEMTIME STRUCT
    wYear       WORD ?
    wMonth      WORD ?
    wDayOfWeek  WORD ?
    wDay        WORD ?
    wHour       WORD ?
    wMinute     WORD ?
    wSecond     WORD ?
    wMilliseconds WORD ?
LPSYSTEMTIME ENDS

localTime LPSYSTEMTIME <>
.code
main PROC   

 invoke GetLocalTime, ADDR localTime    
 invoke ExitProcess,eax 
main ENDP
END main
```

You can pull the current day of the week or month from the localTime STRUCT. Visit my blog [Set up visual studio 10 for masm32 programming](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/category/assembly-masm32/) for details on how to setup visual studio.

Comment: And pull the date out just using the struct. localTime.wDate.. Additionally you don't have to define the proto, nor the struct cause they are already in kernel32

Comment: from this line:GetLocalTime PROTO :DWORD
error A2119: language type must be specified
why?